# What is the type of hinge used in fold-down car tv's?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

[image]

I am trying to find out what type of hinge or mechanism is used in fold down car TV's. I need to buy one for a project I'm working on but dont know the name. See picture above.

Comment: Consider looking for laptop lid hinges. These should be easier to obtain (as replacement parts for laptops) and likely display the same behavior.

Comment: What is your project? Orientation, mass, number of electrical signals which must pass thru hinge, number of "hold angles" ?   Please don't post *how* you want to solve, but **what** you want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

These are not usually simple hinges - they are often designed with cams etc to give a specific movement - so are usually specific to the item.

Think of kitchen cupboard hinges - the simple ones are easy to replace, but some have extending movements so doors can move out to clear other doors...

You may find a hinge that does the movement you require and then you will need to re-manufacture it to cope with the load you will be applying...

Comment: This particular one seems to be simple pin joint. Athough if it is machine actuated it probably really is a fourbar. But yeah eurohinges are typically sixbar mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

The hinge will be similar to the one for the laptop monitor.

[image]

You can search "hinge for LCD monitors" such as [this page](https://www.bing.com/search?q=lcd%20monitor%20hinges&cvid=197e02c1db1b41d18e960de5cac575c9&aqs=edge..69i57j0l2.8409j0j9&FORM=ANAB01&PC=LCTS).